# How can I assign expense items to a client/job/client invoice in GNUCash?

Tags: gnucash

I have a number of expense items (travel, sundries etc) that I incur whilst doing work for a client. At the moment, I add the expenses to the ledger, but I have to remember to manually add each expense to the client invoice to be reimbursed for them.

Is there a way to assign expenses to a client or client job and then have the option to add those items to a client invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've typically added expenses that will be billed to customers at cost directly to their Accounts Receivable.

Example:

Current Assets\AR\Customer01\2017-09-11 Amsterdam Meeting\

Would contain all of the T&L expenses for that trip. When the invoice gets repaid 
by the customer it is marked against the same AR account.